# Preprocessing text data in python

Tags: python, text

There is a text file(a.text) such as the below example.
For each data, I want to add some features like password length, number of uppercase letters, number of lowercase) and rename each file.
How to coding in python?

(example) before

```
!2QqWwee

!Hihellohi!

1111111

12345678
```

(example) after

```
!2QqWwee, 8, 2, 4

!Hihellohi!, 11, 1, 8

11111111, 8, 0, 0

12345678, 8, 0, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this?

```
def UpperLower(each_password):
    CounterDict = {"UpperCount": 0, "LowerCount": 0}
    for each_character in each_password:
        if each_character.isupper():
           CounterDict["UpperCount"] += 1
        elif each_character.islower():
           CounterDict["LowerCount"] += 1
        else:
           pass
    print(each_password, len(each_password), CounterDict["UpperCount"], CounterDict["LowerCount"])

Passwords = ["!2QqWwee", "!Hihellohi!", "11111111", "12345678"]

for each_password in Passwords:
    UpperLower(each_password)
```

Results:

```
# !2QqWwee 8 2 4
# !Hihellohi! 11 1 8
# 11111111 8 0 0
# 12345678 8 0 0
```